# Return formatted object with only positive values

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, filter, reduce

I've an object of objects. Each of my nested object has a price as a nested array which may contain negative values. 
I need to format the object and return a new one with the child objects containing only positive values.

For e.g., 
In the code below, ideally it should only return object with 'TypeB' object as only that has the price with non-negative values.

I tried this, but I guess am missing something. 
Also, can I optimize this using 'reduce' method instead?

Input Object:

```
{
  "TypeA": [
    {
      "price": [
        [
          {
            "amount": -45,
            "currency": "USD"
          }
        ]
      ],
      "name": "ABC",
      "priceDetails": [
        {
          "name": "BASE",
          "price": [
            [
              {
                "amount": -40.00,
                "currency": "USD"
              }
            ]
          ]
        },
        {
          "name": "TAX",
          "price": [
            [
              {
                "amount": -5.00,
                "currency": "USD"
              }
            ]
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  "TypeB": [
    {
      "price": [
        [
          {
            "amount": 0,
            "currency": "USD"
          }
        ]
      ],
      "name": "ABC",
      "priceDetails": [
        {
          "name": "BASE",
          "price": [
            [
              {
                "amount": 0,
                "currency": "USD"
              }
            ]
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Expected Output:

```
{
  "TypeB": [
    {
      "price": [
        [
          {
            "amount": 0,
            "currency": "USD"
          }
        ]
      ],
      "name": "ABC",
      "priceDetails": [
        {
          "name": "BASE",
          "price": [
            [
              {
                "amount": 0,
                "currency": "USD"
              }
            ]
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Code:

```
const data = {
  "TypeA": [{
    "price": [
      [{
        "amount": -45,
        "currency": "USD"
      }]
    ],
    "name": "ABC",
    "priceDetails": [{
        "name": "BASE",
        "price": [
          [{
            "amount": -40.00,
            "currency": "USD"
          }]
        ]
      },
      {
        "name": "TAX",
        "price": [
          [{
            "amount": -5.00,
            "currency": "USD"
          }]
        ]
      }
    ]
  }],
  "TypeB": [{
    "price": [
      [{
        "amount": 0,
        "currency": "USD"
      }]
    ],
    "name": "ABC",
    "priceDetails": [{
      "name": "BASE",
      "price": [
        [{
          "amount": 0,
          "currency": "USD"
        }]
      ]
    }]
  }]
};

const formattedData = Object.values(data).filter(item => {
  return item.map(elem => {
    const itemPrice = elem.price;
    const isPositive = itemPrice[0][0].amount >= 0;
    return isPositive ? elem : false;
  });
});
console.log(formattedData);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
cc = {
  "TypeA": [
    {
      "price": [
        [
          {
            "amount": -45,
            "currency": "USD"
          }
        ]
      ],
      "name": "ABC",
      "priceDetails": [
        {
          "name": "BASE",
          "price": [
            [
              {
                "amount": -40.00,
                "currency": "USD"
              }
            ]
          ]
        },
        {
          "name": "TAX",
          "price": [
            [
              {
                "amount": -5.00,
                "currency": "USD"
              }
            ]
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  "TypeB": [
    {
      "price": [
        [
          {
            "amount": 0,
            "currency": "USD"
          }
        ]
      ],
      "name": "ABC",
      "priceDetails": [
        {
          "name": "BASE",
          "price": [
            [
              {
                "amount": 0,
                "currency": "USD"
              }
            ]
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}

const dd = Object.keys(cc).reduce((acc, item) => {
  if (cc[item][0].price[0][0].amount >= 0) {
    acc[item] = cc[item];
   }
return acc;
}, {});
console.log(dd)
```

Try this

```
const result = Object.keys(data).filter(i => data[i][0].price[0][0].amount >= 0).map(y => data[y])
console.log(result) // positive amount array
```

**Edits** : With reducer

```
const dd = Object.keys(data).reduce((acc, item) => {
  if (data[item][0].price[0][0].amount >= 0) {
    acc[item] = data[item];
   }
return acc;
}, {});
```

Comment: I get an array but expected result is an object which has the original key as well. Please check the expected output in my question above.

Comment: Just updated my answer, hope so this is what you are expecting. Please check snippet. @Sunny

Answer (score 2):

You could filter the data by using various checks and build a new object if a wanted leaf object is found.

```js
function filter(object) {
    if (!object || typeof object !== 'object') return;

    if ('amount' in object) return object.amount >= 0 ? object : undefined;

    if (Array.isArray(object)) {
        var items = object.reduce((r, v) => {
            var temp = filter(v);
            if (temp) r.push(temp);
            return r;
        }, []);
        return items.length ? items : undefined;
    } else {
        var entries = Object.entries(object).reduce((r, [k, v]) => {
            var temp = filter(v);
            if (temp) r.push([k, temp]);
            return r;
        }, []);
        return entries.length ? Object.fromEntries(entries) : undefined;
    }
}

var data = { TypeA: [{ price: [[{ amount: -45, currency: "USD" }]], name: "ABC", priceDetails: [{ name: "BASE", price: [[{ amount: -40, currency: "USD" }]] }, { name: "TAX", price: [[{ amount: -5, currency: "USD" }]] }] }], TypeB: [{ price: [[{ amount: 0, currency: "USD" }]], name: "ABC", priceDetails: [{ name: "BASE", price: [[{ amount: 0, currency: "USD" }]] }] }] },
    result = filter(data);

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to use `Object.entries` to make your object as array and then just `filter` by checking that `every` amount is greater than `0`:

```
const filtered = Object.entries(data).filter(([k, v]) =>
    v.every(s=> s.price.every(s1 => s1.every(s2 => s2.amount >= 0 )))
    && v.every(pd => pd.priceDetails.every(pdp => 
        pdp.price.every(pr => pr.every(prr => prr.amount >= 0))))
);
```

An example:

```js
const data = {
    "TypeA": [{
        "price": [ [{ "amount": -45, "currency": "USD"  }]
        ],
        "name": "ABC",
        "priceDetails": [{
            "name": "BASE",
            "price": [[{  "amount": -40.00, "currency": "USD" }]]
        },
        {
            "name": "TAX",
            "price": [ [{ "amount": -5.00, "currency": "USD" }]]
        }
        ]
    }],
    "TypeB": [{
        "price": [ [{"amount": 0, "currency": "USD" }]],
        "name": "ABC",
        "priceDetails": [{
            "name": "BASE",
            "price": [[{"amount": 0, "currency": "USD"}]]
        }]
    }]
};

const filtered = Object.entries(data).filter(([k, v]) =>
    v.every(s=> s.price.every(s1 => s1.every(s2 => s2.amount >= 0 )))
    && v.every(pd => pd.priceDetails.every(pdp => pdp.price.every(pr => pr.every(prr => prr.amount >= 0))))
);

const result = Object.fromEntries(filtered);
console.log(result);
```